# filter div tag without case sensitive

Tags: jquery, css

how to filter div tag without case sensitive ?

I'm using the code the following.

Following code to work properly but filter is case sensitive!
I need to filter without case sensitive. How do I do it? I have no idea

```
   $('#txtSearchInShip').keyup(function () {
        var searchText = $(this).val();
         if (searchText.length <= 0) {
             $('div .thumbnail').fadeIn("slow");
        }
        else if (searchText.length > 0) {
             $("div .thumbnail .caption p a:contains(" + searchText + ")").parent().parent().parent().parent().show();
             $("div .thumbnail .caption p a:not(:contains(" + searchText + "))").parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/

Comment: Instead of using `parent()` multiple times, you should try jQuery's `has()` method

Comment: @Bigood : i use has() method but not worked for me.

Comment: @karthikr : How do I use it?

Comment: @john THe comments below have a usage example

Comment: @karthikr. sorry. I could not understand the code .

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code in your JS file (for jQuery >= 1.8) :

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

Then, call your method as usual :

```
$("div:contains('John')")
```

Information from [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/) (thanks to [karthikr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1628832/karthikr) for this link).

Comment: i use jQuery >= 1.10.2 .

Comment: @john You can use it then :)

Comment: @john I edited my answer, try to follow the steps : include the first snippet in your code, and then call your `:contains` as usual

Answer (score 0):

well, `contains` is case sensitive... there are two methods of making in case insensitive.. oneway is to overwrite the function and other create new one..

overwrite the jquery :contains. (add this before your code).

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

and use this in script

```
$("div .thumbnail .caption p a:contains(" + searchText + ")").parent().parent().parent().parent().show();
```

this however , overwrites the jquery `contains`.

for creating new one using extend

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
 "containsIN": function(elem, i, match, array) {
      return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
 }
});
```

now you can  use `containsIN` instead of `contains:`, where you need to filter the string with case-insenstive

```
 $("div .thumbnail .caption p a:containsIN(" + searchText + ")").parent().parent().parent().parent().show();
```

[link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/search/label/making%20jQuery%20contains%20Case-Insensitive) to read more about jquery contains case insensitive...

furthermore, i recommened you to use `closest()` or `parents()` rather than just `parent()` many time...